# Implementing a permalink mechanism in Liferay Portlet

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, liferay, permalinks

I am trying to create a permalink system for the portlets I'm developing (Spring MVC, Liferay 6.0.6).
My idea was to create and map a special URL, so I used to append a query string to the current URL. It worked fine until I tried to use the link after a log-out/log-in.

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_auth=ASDFGH&p_p_id=xviewer_WAR_xviewer_INSTANCE_Yz9i&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_xviewer_WAR_xviewer_INSTANCE_Yz9i_action=permalink&xQuery=asd
```

the problem is that Liferay screams about not enough privileges, which of course make sense. 
How should I do it?

Comment: What are you wanting this permalinks to be pointing to? Items of Web Content or something else?

Comment: It's a link to a search result table (rendered dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with `p_auth=ASDFGH`
Can you, for test, put

```
auth.token.check.enabled=false
```

in `portal-ext.properties`, restart server, make your link again and test it.

If it works than you have several options to disable token check for specific portlet/action.

Following properties are "Authentication Token" settings from portal.properties

```
#
# Set this to true to enable authentication token security checks. The
# checks can be disabled for specific actions via the property
# "auth.token.ignore.actions" or for specific portlets via the init
# parameter "check-auth-token" in portlet.xml.
#
auth.token.check.enabled=true

#
# Set the authentication token class. This class must implement
# com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthToken. This class is used to prevent
# CSRF attacks. See http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-8399 for more
# information.
#
auth.token.impl=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SessionAuthToken

#
# Input a list of comma delimited struts actions that will not be checked
# for an authentication token.
#
auth.token.ignore.actions=\
    /asset/rss,\
    \
    /blogs/rss,\
    \
    /document_library/edit_file_entry,\
    \
    /journal/rss,\
    \
    /image_gallery/edit_image,\
    \
    /login/login,\
    \
    /message_boards/rss,\
    \
    /wiki/edit_page_attachment,\
    /wiki/rss

#
# Set the shared secret that is used for requests where it is not possible
# to generate an authentication token (i.e. WSRP).
#
auth.token.shared.secret=BAHyWOT9TbPB
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me, what are the consequences of disabling the token?
BTW,  the ASDF.. token was just a mock ;-)

Comment: Pleas take a look at http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token

Comment: Thank you very much ;) This is the information I need. BTW. Can a RENDER phase link be shared as a permalink?

Comment: Yes, you need to change p_p_lifecycle=1 to p_p_lifecycle=0 in url. Lifecycle phases are render = 0, action = 1, resource = 2.